# Convert cURL (--data-binary) Post Command to RestSharp Code

Tags: curl, restsharp

How to convert this cURL to [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)?

curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64'

This is how one can write records to an InfluxDB instance using cURL but I need the RestSharp equivalent.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Figured that out so answering my question:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8086");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");
var request = new RestRequest ("write?db=mydb", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("text/plain", "cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute (request);
var content = response.Content;
Console.WriteLine (content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the curl into Postman;
[image]

And then select 'Rest Sharp' from the code snippets menu on the right-hand side.
[image]